# How can I separate data combined into single rows?

Tags: r

I'm working with a dataset that looks something like this, except there are many more columns with data like "serial" and "loc":

```
start <-c(1,8,16,24,28,32)
end   <-c(4,9,20,27,30,45)
serial<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
loc<-c(8,63,90,32,89,75)
dataset<-data.frame(cbind(start,end, serial,loc))
```

Here each row actually represents a run of consecutive integers; I'd like to make each of those consecutive integers into its own row and conserve the other attributes of that row.  "start" indicates the beginning of a run and "end" represents the end of the run.  So, for example, in the first row in "dataset", I would like to have that row separated into four rows: one for 1, one for 2, one for 3, and one for 4.  Likewise, the second row in "dataset" would be split into two rows: one for 8 and one for 9 etc.

Thus the output for running just the first two lines of "dataset" would look like:

```
split serial loc
    1 1 8
    2 1 8
    3 1 8
    4 1 8
    8 2 63
    9 2 63
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach sticking with base R.

```
temp <- mapply(seq, dataset$start, dataset$end)
dataset2 <- data.frame(serial = rep(dataset$serial, sapply(temp, length)),
                       index = unlist(temp),
                       loc = rep(dataset$loc, sapply(temp, length)))
list(head(dataset2), tail(dataset2))
# [[1]]
#   serial index loc
# 1      1     1   8
# 2      1     2   8
# 3      1     3   8
# 4      1     4   8
# 5      2     8  63
# 6      2     9  63
# 
# [[2]]
#    serial index loc
# 27      6    40  75
# 28      6    41  75
# 29      6    42  75
# 30      6    43  75
# 31      6    44  75
# 32      6    45  75
```

Answer (score 3):

A `data.table` solution assuming serial is a unique row identifier

```
library(data.table)
DA <- as.data.table(dataset)
DB <- DA[,list(index = seq(start,end, by = 1), loc),by = serial]
```

If `serial` is not a unique row identifier then

```
DB <- DA[, list(index = seq(start,end, by = 1), loc, serial), by = list(rowid = seq_len(nrow(DA)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# create the ranges
ranges <- mapply(seq, dataset$start, dataset$end)

# create the tables
tables <- lapply(seq(ranges), function(i) 
             cbind(split=ranges[[i]], dataset[i, c("serial", "loc")]) ) 

# to put all the tables in one matrix: 
do.call(rbind, tables)
```

Comment: Using apply on a `data.frame` is not particularly safe, as it will coerce to a matrix of the same type. I don't see how the second line does what the OP wants. (or perhaps I am misunderstanding)

Comment: @mnel, the second line had a mistake, which is now fixed.  Thanks for pointing out the issue with `apply` and data frames.  I hadnt realized that, although it does make sense. Does it always coerce into matrix (i.e. just by virtue of using apply) or only when `FUN` would require such an action?

Comment: It will always coerce to an matrix (or array but this is not possible for a data.frame). Looking at the source code the lines are `if (is.object(X)) 
        {X <- if (dl == 2L) { as.matrix(X)} else {as.array(X)}}`